# using module.modulemap to integrate frameworks' objC header in Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a framework that contains Objective-C header files. I want to use these header files in the Swift project, in which I am importing this framework.

There are two ways to do it

1) create bridging header file - but, then user will be dependent to create this file, while integrating the framework

2) create module.modulemap file - that I can ship with my framework and user can add it to (which build setting).... <- I need help here

I've tried `Import Paths` in `Swift Compiler - Search Paths` and `Module Map  File` in `Packaging`

In both the cases, I am not able to import the header `RandomHeader`.

My `module.modulemap` looks like below

```
module ToBeShippedFramework
{
    header "RandomPublicHeader.h"
    export *
}
```

Is there something different that I need to do?

**PS**: Please put in comments if you need some more info to understand this question more clearly.